# Remove an image before uploding it with multer and node.js in a react native application

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo, multer

I have an application that a user can upload the profile picture and what I want to do is remove the picture that was stored before and then upload the new one, but the code that I have is just removing the picture which makes me think that is uploading it first.

```
const UploadProfileImage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination(req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, "./src/UserImages");
  },
  filename(req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, `${file.originalname}`);
  },
});

const upload = multer({
  fileFilter: (req, file, callback) => {
    let files = fs.readdirSync(UserImagesPath);
    console.log(files.includes(req.user.user_img));
    if (files.includes(req.user.user_img)) {
      fs.unlinkSync(
        path.join(__dirname, "../UserImages") + "\\" + req.user.user_img
      );
      console.log("Done");
    }
  },
  storage: UploadProfileImage,
});
```

Why this code doesn't work?

And I have another question!

When I upload the image without the code that deletes the image the actual picture changes but in the frontend is still showing an image that supposedly doesn't exist and I think it can still show that image because it is in cache.
How can I remove an image from the cache?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `multer` to remove the image, but `fs` can help you do it. You can create a middleware to do that.

```
const { promisify } = require('util')

const unlinkProm = promisify(fs.unlink);



app.get('path', UploadProfileImage, (req, res) => {
      // remove the image after saving one
      // make sure you provide the path of older image
       try {
       const res = await unlinkProm(oldImagePath);
       res.send('udpated data')
       } catch (e) {
         console.log(e);
       }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the example but I already solved that issue.
I have another problem now that is the photo that the frontend is showing does not exist but he still can access it because the program saved it in cache I suppose. Do you know how to remove something from the cache?

Comment: Yes, try changing the name of the image and it will automatically take new one. This one is the simplest.